# Iterate through all tile properties in layer

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I managed to iterate through all CCSprites (tiles) in a Tiled layer. However, what I really need it is to iterate through all the *properties* (NSDictionaries)  of all tiles within the layer. How would I do such? I don't really need to get the CCSprites, just the property list.

Comment: i assume you made your own wrapper class for CCSprite and you've added properties to that wrapper class, correct?

Comment: Well, not exactly. You see, the program Tiled lets you put properties to your tileset's tiles (such properties are like a dictionary - you give a key and a value). In Cocos2d, it is possible to get a tile at X position and read such properties. I need to iterate through all tile properties in the layer. I can't find a way to iterate through all tiles in a layer.

Comment: Given I can check the properties for a tile at (X,Y) position, some people would suggest me to simply "iterate through all Xs and Ys in the layer so I can get all the properties". Well, the problem is that I keep getting Assertion Failures if I use a position where a tile doesn't exist. Such errors seem to cause some lag or other unexpected results in gameplay...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `-(NSDictionary*)propertiesForGID:(unsigned int)GID` method for `CCTMXTiledMap` to get the tile properties.

But first you need to know the GID of the tile. Get that from `-(uint32_t) tileGIDAt:(CGPoint)pos` method for `CCTMXLayer`:

```
CGPoint pos = ccp(2,1);
uint gid = [layer tileGIDAt:pos];
if (gid > 0) {
    NSDictionary *tileProperty = [tiledMap propertiesForGID:gid];

    // do stuff here
}
```

EDIT: here is how to iterate through all tiles on a `CCTMXLayer`:

```
for (NSUInteger y = 0; y < tmxLayer.layerSize.height; y++) {
    for (NSUInteger x = 0; x < tmxLayer.layerSize.width; x++) {
        NSUInteger pos = x + tmxLayer.layerSize.width * y;
        uint32_t gid = tmxLayer.tiles[pos];
        if (gid > 0) {
            NSDictionary *tileProperty = [tiledMap propertiesForGID:gid];

            // do stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to iterate through all the tiles first? I can check for a specific tile's properties, but I'd like to check for all the tiles in a layer first.